# NotifyDataSetChanged does not update the RecyclerView correctly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, notifydatasetchanged

I am trying to implement a fairly basic logic within my recyclerview adapter but `notifyDataSetChanged()` is giving me quite the headache.

I have a filter method that looks like this:

```
fun filter(category: Int) {
    Thread(Runnable {
        activeFiltered!!.clear()

        if (category == -1) {
            filterAll()
        } else {
            filterCategory(category)
        }

        (mContext as Activity).runOnUiThread {
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }).start()
}
```

where `filterAll()` and `filterCategory()` functions are quite easy:

```
private fun filterAll() {
    activeFiltered?.addAll(tempList!!)
}

private fun filterCategory(category: Int) {
    for (sub in tempList!!) {
        if (sub.category == category) {
            activeFiltered?.add(sub)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code and filter the list by category the activeFiltered list is updated correctly and contains the items I expect, but when `notifyDataSetChanged()` is run it only cuts the list's range without updating the items.

Is there a way to fix this?

I also tried, instead of notifyDataSetChanged() to use:

```
activeFiltered!!.forEachIndexed {index, _ ->  notifyItemChanged(index)}
```

but the problem is still there.

It isn't a threading issue either since I tried putting the whole logic in the main thread and the list still wasn't updated correctly.

This is my `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ActiveViewHolder, pos: Int) {
    sub = activeFiltered!![pos]
    inflateView()

}
```

This is where I inflate my text, sub is the instance variable set in the `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
private fun inflateView() {
        viewHolder.title.text = sub.title
    }
```

Comment: This clearly isn't a filtering problem, I debugged it throughout and the list is the one I expect.

Comment: can you please post the `onBindViewHolder` of your RV

Comment: no, this is the 3rd time when you have problem with `notifyDataSetChanged` in your adapter, do you still insist it has some bigs?

Comment: @MadScientist here, I uploaded my `onBindViewHolder()`, the `inflateView()` method only inflated the color basically

Comment: and the colors are coming wrong right? i.e the items in your list are perfect but the data that is being set is not, can you please the inflateView method as well?

Comment: @pskink I don't say it's bug, just that the mistake isn't in the filter

Comment: ok so instead of using not synchronized multiple threads, why dont you use generic `Filterable` adapter? there are lot of them on the net/arsenal/github

Comment: @MadScientist no, the colors are right, let me explain: Let's say I have a list with "dog, lion, tiger, cat" and I wanna filter out only the house animals, after the `filter()` function is run I get this list: "dog, cat", after `notifyDataSetChanged()` is run the recyclerView displays "dog, lion" (two elements, like the filteredList but not the right ones). Hope I explained alright lol

Comment: yep i got it, it means the list you're using to display is sliced, can you post the code where you are setting the text, are you trying to display it from the main list or the temp one? also your size is bound by `activeFiltered.size` right?

Comment: @MadScientist I am doing everything on the `activeFiltered` list, the `tempList` is only a backup for the original list. and yes, my size is bound to `activeFiltered.size`

Comment: assuming `sub` is a global you have and is accessed from multiple thread without being `volatile` could you try passing the index of the element as a parameter to the `inflate` method instead of accessing a global inside.

Comment: @MadScientist I tried it, but the problem persists. You can see in the updated question how I modified the code

Comment: I am not sure about the internals of the RV, hence I post this as comment. The reason for the behaviour of your implementation is 1) First RV calls the onCreateVH for position 0. You created and stored a VH. 2) Next RV calls onBindVH for position 0. You updated the stored VH. 3) This happens for say next three positions and everything is fine. 4) Now the list data changes and notify...() is called. 5) Now the RV do not call onCreateVH, since it already have four VH in hand. It tries to reuse them. 6) It passes one of them in onBindVH. But you are updating the stored VH and not the passed VH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the implementation of `onBindViewHolder()` is incorrect. In order to update a list item, the passed in `viewHolder` parameter should be used (not the `viewHolder` you created in the `onCreateViewHolder()`).

The correct implementation should be like

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ActiveViewHolder, pos: Int) {
    val sub = activeFiltered!![pos]
    inflateView(viewHolder, sub)
}

private fun inflateView(viewHolder: ActiveViewHolder, sub: <YourDataType>) {
    viewHolder.title.text = sub.title
}
```

By the way, it is not a good practice to hold something as a member field in order to access it in several methods. Feel free to pass it as arguments to such methods. In the above code I passed the `sub` as argument and not stored it as a member.

And also it is not necessary to hold the `viewHolder` that you create in `onCreateViewHolder()`. We mostly need them in some callback methods (like `onBindViewHolder()`, etc) and these methods will receive the right `viewHolder` as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the original array in `onBindView()` instead of the filtered one.

Comment: In the onBindView I'm getting the elements out of the filteredList which is the one modified by the filter() function, doesn't onBindView() get called again after notifyDataSetChanged() is run?